# Airflow - DAG fails after few weeks

Tags: docker, airflow

I have some issue with my dags in airflow, I got around 10 dags running.

Everything works perfectly but after a few weeks we always end up with everything failing.

Most of the dag getting data form an api get this error :

```
[2024-02-05T19:00:01.155+0000] {DAGNAME.py:87} ERROR - An error occured: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='api.XXXXXX-au.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /api/v2/forms/15c8c779-5c38-4d9a-a474-37cb7ce8b1b9.json?schema=true (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7fe465b22cd0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution'))
```

But this error has nothing to do with the API I try to request because I tested it on my computer and it is working fine (same api key and no error).

On the other end another dag is failing due to :

```
Request URL is missing an 'http://' or 'https://' protocol. or https error
```

I'm really confused, eveyrthing is running fine and then somehow without changing anything everything fails.

Restarting docker container fix it.
But it is not ideal.

Do you have an idea ?

When I run the script to update dags I usually get :

"WARNING:root:OSError while attempting to symlink the latest log directory"

But it has never been an issue as the log are still visible in airflow and the log folder when executed through airflow or through airflow scheduler.

Maybe i'm missing something important in the setup, not sure where to look.

I also check the container ressources, CPU and container memory usage were all low.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Where did you put the API connection? In the Airflow Connection or hardcoded in the DAG?

Comment: It is hardcoded in the dag, the dag will read a config file and then request data from the API. It is working perfectly fine now, but i'm pretty sure it will collapse after 30 days. I didn't know it could be setup using an airflow connection which might be a good practice I missed

Comment: Yes, it's better not to hardcode connection. Read on how to create the HTTP connection in Airflow here -> https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-http/stable/connections/http.html#http-connection